# Azure IoT Central - Enum value displaying blank value in Dashboard

Tags: azure-iot-central

We are using a telemetry property "Bulb status" with an enum as shown below

```
"@id": "urn:veeazigbeeappdemo:ZigbeeDeviceTemplate_12r3:on_off:1",
      "@type": "Telemetry",
      "displayName": {
        "en": "Bulb Status"
      },
      "name": "on_off",
      "schema": {
        "@id": "urn:veeazigbeeappdemo:ZigbeeDeviceTemplate_12r3:on_off:hxdsbx1pp:1",
        "@type": "Enum",
        "displayName": {
          "en": "Enum"
        },
        "valueSchema": "string",
        "enumValues": [
          {
            "@id": "urn:veeazigbeeappdemo:ZigbeeDeviceTemplate_12r3:on_off:hxdsbx1pp:On:1",
            "@type": "EnumValue",
            "displayName": {
              "en": "On"
            },
            "enumValue": "1",
            "name": "On"
          },
          {
            "@id": "urn:veeazigbeeappdemo:ZigbeeDeviceTemplate_12r3:on_off:hxdsbx1pp:Off:1",
            "@type": "EnumValue",
            "displayName": {
              "en": "Off"
            },
            "enumValue": "0",
            "name": "Off"
          }
        ]
      }
```

The tile is made to display "Last Known value" in Template

[image: Bulb status]

When we send a payload as follows

> payload = '{"on_off": %s}' % (random.choice([0, 1]))

we are getting the Bulb status correctly displayed as follows

[image: Bulb status on]

when we send a payload which **doesn't have Bulb status(on_off)** telemetry property in it as below

> payload = '{"current_level": %f}' % random.randrange(10.0, 100.0)

we are getting the Bulb status being shown as blank as follows

[image: Bulb status blank]

Correct Behaviour:
The Bulb status should show last know value from on_off property and should not display as blank when we don't send that telemetry property.

**This kind of behavior with enum is causing an issue for us. Please provide the solution to overcome this.**

Please let me know Where can I post this as a bug of Enum in Azure IoT Central?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an enum type is handling a null value differently than the other types. It seems to me, the unmodeled data should be not modify a dashboard.

As a workaround, Can you change type to the SemanticType/State? The State History is working well:

[image]

[image]

The feedback to the IoT Central team is [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/911455-azure-iot-central).

Comment: I checked today, the bug seems to be fixed with enum.

Comment: @HariharnathPaduchuru, that's correct. Thanks for pointing this issue and also how fast the IoT Central team fixed it.